# Finding List Intersection using Python List Slices & recursion

Tags: python, recursion, slice

```
def findIntersection(list1, list2):
    if list1 == [] or list2 == []:
        return []
    elif list1[0] < list2[0]:
        return [list1[0]] + findIntersection(list[1:], list2)
    elif list1[0] > list2[0]:
        return [list2[0]] + findIntersection(list1, list2[1:])
    else:
        return ([list1[0]] + findIntersection(list1[1:], list2[1:]))
```

This is the code I have written so far, and the end goal is to find the intersection of two lists. So for instance, findIntersection([1,2,4], [0,2,3]) == [2] or findIntersection([0,2,3,5], [1,2,4,5,6]) == [2,5].

Where should I start and what am I doing wrong. Also more explanation of python slices would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you carefully return elements that are not in the intersection:

```
elif list1[0] < list2[0]:
    return [list1[0]] + findIntersection(list[1:], list2)
elif list1[0] > list2[0]:
    return [list2[0]] + findIntersection(list1, list2[1:])
else:
    return ([list1[0]] + findIntersection(list1[1:], list2[1:]))
```

Of these three cases, the *only* one that identifies a valid intersection element, is the last one: the element is in both lists.

For the other two, your recursion is correct, but adding the lower element is an error.  You have to *discard* this element, because you *know* it isn't in both lists.

```
elif list1[0] < list2[0]:
    # Drop the lowest element of list1 and recur
    return findIntersection(list[1:], list2)
elif list1[0] > list2[0]:
    # Drop the lowest element of list2 and recur
    return findIntersection(list1, list2[1:])
else:
    The element is in both lists; add it to the solution and recur.
    return ([list1[0]] + findIntersection(list1[1:], list2[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

`[i for i in list1 if i in list2]`

Uses list comprehension. Cycles though each element in list1 and adds them to a new list if and only if they are found in list2.

If you want to use slicing and recursion, then you're very close... you only want to include an element in the intersection list if its in both lists - that's only true in the final `else`. Also you have a typo in your code - `list` where should be `list1`. Note also that this method requires the input lists to be sorted (either both ascending or both descending).

```
def findIntersection(list1, list2):
    if list1 == [] or list2 == []:
        return []
    elif list1[0] < list2[0]:
        return findIntersection(list1[1:], list2)
    elif list1[0] > list2[0]:
        return findIntersection(list1, list2[1:])
    else:
        return [list1[0]] + findIntersection(list1[1:], list2[1:])

list1 = [0,2,3,5]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print(findIntersection(list1, list2))
```

Returns `[2,3,5]`

Comment: This is an efficient answer, however I'm trying to use Python slicing/recursion so I can further understand the concept.

Comment: Ah. Sorry missed that. If I understand the concept of how you are trying to do it then your lists need to be sorted in ascending order first?

Comment: Correct. So in the few test cases that I'm utilizing, I'm looking at lists that are already set in ascending order.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I cant believe I didnt see such an obvious error in my code. How would you explain the concept of Python slicing in its simplest form? I find it to be the splitting of a list into first and rest but what benefits does it offer?