# Python intersection of 2 arrays without using loops/functions

Tags: python, algorithm

I have some problems with this task:

> write in recursive functions which (NOTE: you can't use loops.):

> 3.1 Will display on the screen the common part of two sorted arrays

> 3.2 Will write the back of the word/array on the screen

Right now I have rest of the exercise:

```
firstArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
secondArray = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

#1 function - print first element
def printFirstElement():
    firstElemenet = firstArray[0]
    print(firstElemenet)
    
printFirstElement()

#2 function - print all without first element
def printAllWithouthFirstElemenet():
   arrayWithoutFirstElement = firstArray[1:]
   print(arrayWithoutFirstElement)
   
printAllWithouthFirstElemenet()

#3 functin - return information if array is empty 
def checkArrayEmptiness():
    if firstArray:
        print("Array has somehting")
    else:
        print("Array is empty")
    
checkArrayEmptiness()

##rest code should be here
```

I really don't have idea what I could write more, someone could help me?

Edit 1

> Without ready-made solutions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding List Intersection using Python List Slices & recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64018760/finding-list-intersection-using-python-list-slices-recursion)

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) What have you already tried, and what do you need help with exactly? You can [edit] to clarify. See [ask] if you want more tips.

Answer (score 1):

You can use python [set](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set).
Something like:

```py
    print(set(firstArray).intersection(secondArray))
```

In most cases it will be smart to use Python built in solutions, as they are more efficient for the general case.

But, in case you do need it, try looking at this duplicate question: [Finding List Intersection using Python List Slices & recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64018760/finding-list-intersection-using-python-list-slices-recursion)